# getting city name from coordinates

Tags: java, android, coordinates

My app fetches the users coordinates. Now I try to get the name of the city where the coordinates belong to. I searched the other threads, but I didn‘t find something helpful or new about it. My textView that should show the address name just stays empty, or is it a wrong way to fetch an address?

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    double lat;
    double lon;
    Button btnLoc;
    TextView textView7;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView textView7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);

        btnLoc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGetLoc);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 123);

        btnLoc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                GPSTracker gt = new GPSTracker(getApplicationContext());
                Location location = gt.getLocation();

                if (location == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS unable to get Value", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {

                    double lat = location.getLatitude();
                    double lon = location.getLongitude();

                    TextView textView5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
                    textView5.setText(String.valueOf(lat));

                    TextView textView6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
                    textView6.setText(String.valueOf(lon));

                }
            }
        });

        try {

            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lon, 1);
            if (addresses.size() > 0)

                textView7.setText(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things I noticed.

1. You are not initializing the lat and long that you defined in your activity scope.

   double lat;
   double lon;

These will remain null when you pass them into your function

```
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lon, 1);
```

So you may want to try removing the types from your lat/long variables inside your click function.

```
            - double lat = location.getLatitude();
            - double lon = location.getLongitude();


            + lat = location.getLatitude();
            + lon = location.getLongitude();
```

2. Try to fetch your results **after** you have clicked. Not after you initialize the click listener. Since you don't have a proper callback setup to fire after you have fetched your location (I'm assuming it's an asynchronous call), you can temporarily overcome this by setting up another button/click listener that you can click after you have fetched your coordinates.

If that doesn't work take a look at this short helpful guide
https://www.kerstner.at/2013/08/convert-gps-coordinates-to-address-using-google-geocoding-api-in-java/

Cheers

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad. So they are initialized, when I remove the „double“ in the fetching methods right? I don‘t know what you mean by fetching the results after the click. Shouldn‘t the variables be gotten when the button is clicked?

Comment: Yes but this snippet: Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault()); Only runs once. It is not inside your click listener.